# Implement ImagePicker to Set Image From Gallery or Camera?

Tags: swift5

I created a class `ImagePickerManager` using following Code:

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    class ImagePickerManager: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        var picker = UIImagePickerController();
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        var viewController: UIViewController?
        var pickImageCallback : ((UIImage) -> ())?;

        override init(){
            super.init()
        }

        func pickImage(_ viewController: UIViewController, _ callback: @escaping ((UIImage) -> ())) {
            pickImageCallback = callback;
            self.viewController = viewController;

            let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default){
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openCamera()
            }
            let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default){
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openGallery()
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel){
                UIAlertAction in
            }

            // Add the actions
            picker.delegate = self
            alert.addAction(cameraAction)
            alert.addAction(galleryAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.viewController!.view
            viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func openCamera(){
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)){
                picker.sourceType = .camera
                self.viewController!.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alertWarning = UIAlertView(title:"Warning", message: "You don't have camera", delegate:nil,
cancelButtonTitle:"OK", otherButtonTitles:"")
                alertWarning.show()
            }
        }
        func openGallery(){
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.viewController!.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        //for swift below 4.2
        //func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String
: Any]) {
        //    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        //    pickImageCallback?(image)
        //}

        // For Swift 4.2+
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:
[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
                fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
            }
            pickImageCallback?(image)
        }  
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, pickedImage: UIImage?) {
        } 
    }'
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func btnProfileImgClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {  
        ImagePickerManager().pickImage(self){ image in
            self.btnProfile.setImage(image, for: .normal)
            self.imgP = image
        }
}
```